# could you convert this line of c# into vb.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I tried many things but I always get "cannot convert string to membershipuser"

from the [ASP.Net MVC Membership Starter Kit](http://www.codeplex.com/MvcMembership)

this line from file ListUsers.aspx

```
var users = (ViewData["Users"] as List<MembershipUser>);
```

ViewData["Users"] come from

```
    public virtual ViewResult Index( int? pageIndex, int? pageSize )
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Membership Administration";
        int totalRecords;
        var members = Membership.GetAllUsers( pageIndex ?? 0, pageSize ?? 25, out totalRecords );
        ViewData["Users"] = ToList<MembershipUser>( members );
        ViewData["Roles"] = dotNetRoles.GetAllRoles().ToList();
        return View( "ListUsers" );
    }
```

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Dim users = TryCast(ViewData("Users"), List(Of MembershipUser))
```